# Java JNA for communication with I2C on embedded Ubuntu(BeagleBone Black)

Tags: java, c, jna, ioctl, beagleboneblack

I am using JNA library to call native C on a BeagleBone for communication to the I2C bus.  Communication to I2C bus requires low level file actions such as open, ioctl, close, read, and write.  I am able to open the bus file no problem but I cannot get ioctl to work.  If I could get this working I believe I would have I2C function working on either BeagleBone Black or Raspberry Pi.  Here is my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.*;

public class Main {

```
static Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping libC = new Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping();

public static int O_RDWR = 0x00000002;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main(){

    System.setProperty("jna.library.path","/usr/lib/cgi-bin/jna");

    //Open I2C Bus 1 file
    String fileName = "/dev/i2c-1";

    int file = libC.open(fileName, O_RDWR);
    if(file<0){
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("File open for reading and writing");
    }
    //Print out returned value from file open
    System.out.println(file);

    //initiate connection to chip.  I2C chip I am using mounts on 0x21
    int[] address = {33};

    int i2c_slave  = 1795;

    //This is what fails.  I always get -1 back.
    int iocntl = libC.ioctl(file, i2c_slave, address);
    //Print returned value after ioctl action
    System.out.println("fcntl = "+iocntl);

    if(iocntl<0){
        System.out.println("error on libC.ioctl");
        libC.close(file);
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("ioctl complete");
    }

    //Initialize communication to chip
    byte[] buf = {0,0};

    if(libC.write(file, buf, 2) != 2){
        System.out.println("error writing");
        libC.close(file);
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("I2C chip initialized");
    }

    while(true){
        if(turnOnAllRelays(file)){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                turnOffAllRelays(file);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}

public boolean turnOnAllRelays(int file){
    byte[] buffer = {0xA,0xF};
    if(libC.write(file, buffer, 2) != 2){
        System.out.println("all relays on");
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("failed to turn all relays on");
        libC.close(file);
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean turnOffAllRelays(int file){
    byte[] buffer = {0xA, 0x0};
    if(libC.write(file, buffer, 2) != 2){
        System.out.println("all relays off");
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("failed to turn all relays off");
        libC.close(file);
        return false;
    }
}

public interface Linux_C_lib extends com.sun.jna.Library {

    public long memcpy(int[] dst, short[] src, long n);

    public int memcpy(int[] dst, short[] src, int n);

    public int pipe(int[] fds);

    public int tcdrain(int fd);

    public int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, int arg);

    public int ioctl(int fd, int cmd, int[] arg);

    public int open(String path, int flags);

    public int close(int fd);

    public int write(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);

    public int read(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);

    public long write(int fd, byte[] buffer, long count);

    public long read(int fd, byte[] buffer, long count);

    public int select(int n, int[] read, int[] write, int[] error, timeval timeout);

    public int poll(int[] fds, int nfds, int timeout);

    public int tcflush(int fd, int qs);

    public void perror(String msg);

    public int tcsendbreak(int fd, int duration);

    static public class timeval extends Structure {
        public NativeLong tv_sec;
        public NativeLong tv_usec;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(//
                    "tv_sec",//
                    "tv_usec"//
                    );
        }

        public timeval(jtermios.TimeVal timeout) {
            tv_sec = new NativeLong(timeout.tv_sec);
            tv_usec = new NativeLong(timeout.tv_usec);
        }
    }
}

public static class Linux_C_lib_DirectMapping implements Linux_C_lib {

    native public long memcpy(int[] dst, short[] src, long n);

    native public int memcpy(int[] dst, short[] src, int n);

    native public int pipe(int[] fds);

    native public int tcdrain(int fd);

    native public int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, int arg);

    native public int ioctl(int fd, int cmd, int[] arg);

    native public int open(String path, int flags);

    native public int close(int fd);

    native public int write(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);

    native public int read(int fd, byte[] buffer, int count);

    native public long write(int fd, byte[] buffer, long count);

    native public long read(int fd, byte[] buffer, long count);

    native public int select(int n, int[] read, int[] write, int[] error, timeval timeout);

    native public int poll(int[] fds, int nfds, int timeout);

    native public int tcflush(int fd, int qs);

    native public void perror(String msg);

    native public int tcsendbreak(int fd, int duration);

    static {
        try {
            Native.register("c");
            System.out.println("registered to c library");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Calling ioctl I always get back -1.  I am not familiar with this function since I have not done much C programming but accordingly to the example code from Linux here it means the function failed:
http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices

I should note that I got the idea to use JNA for these functions from the developer of purjavacomm who seemed to use it successfully.

Anyone have any ideas on where Im going wrong?

Comment: Based on your referenced example, the `addr` argument to `ioctl()` should be a `NativeLong`, not a pointer.

Comment: Hi @technomage That is an excellent point.  I completely overlooked that.  I2C detect shows the controller having a hex address of 0x21.  The documentation says it needs to be padded to the left.  Any suggestions on how to convert?

Comment: It's zero padded on the left, which just means turning a 7 bit number into an 8 bit number with the top bit a zero -- so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @tgdavies actually a native `long` is going to be 32 bits or 64 bits, but your point is correct.  Pass in a value of the correct size, and the value will be zero-extended before it even reaches the `ioctl` command.

Comment: I have edited my code above.  I know that the address needs to be 0x21 which is a hex byte.  I converted that to Decimal and it came out to 33 so I used that for the address.  I also know the I2C_Slave value should be 0x0703 in hex which converts to 1795 in Decimal so I converted that value.  Still no luck though.  The ioctl call is still returning -1.  Kind of at a loss on this.